# How to enable mime types in apache - puppet/vagrant box setup?

Tags: apache, centos, vagrant, puppet, mime-types

Currently have the following in a webserver.pp file:

```
class { 'apache':
    default_vhost => false,
    mime_types_additional => {
      'AddType' => {
        'application/font-woff' => '.woff'
      }
    }
  }
```

After looking at the output to /etc/httpd/conf.d/mime.conf I can see that the output does indeed include:

'AddType application/font-woff .woff'

however, this doesn't seem to take affect when serving the font as it's served with Content-Type:text/html.

Is there some flag I'm missing to enable the mime types? - I'm totally new to puppet deployments so scratching my head with this.

Vagrant Box:
CentOS 6.6 x86

Comment: Which Puppet module for provisioning Apache are you using?

Comment: It's the Puppet labs own puppet module from Forge: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apache